# Get output as a list of lists

Tags: python, datetime

Have a list of sets as follows:

```
expiry = [{'20180830', '20180928', '20181025'},
          {'20180830', '20180927', '20181026'},
          {'20180830', '20180927', '20181025'}]
```

and a function:

```
def get_dte(Expiry):
    exp_date = datetime.strptime(Expiry, '%Y%m%d')
    dte = (exp_date- datetime.now()).days
    return dte
```

How to get the output of the function in the same form of inputs (list of sets)?

```
[get_dte(i) for elem in expiry for i in elem]
```

produces:

```
[61, 90, 33, 61, 89, 34, 61, 89, 33]
```

...and need is for:

```
[{61, 90, 33}, {61, 89, 34}, {61, 89, 33}]
```

Comment: `print( [{get_dte(i) for i in elem } for elem in expiry] )` ?

Comment: output should be list of dicts or list of lists?

Comment: list of sets (not dicts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to iterate each elements of expiry separately :

```
>>> [{get_dte(j) for j in i} for i in expiry]
[{33, 62, 89}, {33, 61, 90}, {33, 61, 89}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need a slight modification in your list comprehension.

**Try:**

```
from datetime import datetime

expiry = [{'20180830', '20180928', '20181025'},
          {'20180830', '20180927', '20181026'},
          {'20180830', '20180927', '20181025'}]

def get_dte(Expiry):
    exp_date = datetime.strptime(Expiry, '%Y%m%d')
    dte = (exp_date- datetime.now()).days
    return dte

print( [{get_dte(i) for i in elem } for elem in expiry] )
```

**Output:**

```
[{89, 33, 62}, {33, 90, 61}, {89, 33, 61}]
```